# useEffect cleanup function execution time

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I have the following `useEffect` that fetches data:

```
useEffect(() => {
    let didCancel = false;

    fetch(url).then(response => {
        if(!didCancel) {
            setState(response)
        }
    })

    return () => {
        didCancel = true;
    }
}, [url])
```

However Sentry caught a bug in production pointing to the `setState(response)` line:

```
"Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node"
```

Is there a possibility that a response arrives before the `useEffect` cleanup had a chance to run? I would expect that `didCancel` would always be true.

Comment: The error message you posted and the fetch code seem to not be related. The JavaScript execution runs in a singlet-hreaded UI thread. The response handling cannot kick in between a cleanup during component unmounting.

Comment: Maybe it is better to use [`AbortController`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/API/AbortController) for actually canceling request